# Twig syntax highlighting in PHPStorm?

Tags: templating

Does anyone know of a way to instruct PHPStorm to treat Craft templates as Twig files, without globally assigning all `.html` files to be interpreted as Twig? Since Craft templates don't use the `.twig` extension, PHPStorm thinks they're HTML.

On that note, why doesn't Craft use .twig extensions? I assume P&T doesn't want to scare away users who are comfortable with HTML but not Twig?

Comment: You can use the .twig extension with Craft if you want to. I do, and syntax highlighting (I use Sublime though) is the main reason.

Comment: I would also assume that any worthwhile twig filter is also going to highlight html properly as well, so I don't see any reason not to interpret all `.html` files as HTMLTwig files. Besides, I believe you can set it on a project basis (although don't ask me how — but might be worth looking into).

Comment: I wish you could set it on a per-project basis, but I can't find any way to do that.

Comment: Haven't tested it, but the docs seem to suggest that you can specify filetypes on a per-project basis. See [Project and IDE settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/project-and-ide-settings.html) and [Creating and registering Filetypes](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/creating-and-registering-file-types.html)

Answer (score 15):

Under the PhpStorm preferences, go Editor->File Types->Twig and add `*.html` as a Registered Pattern.[image]

Comment: Yea, I was hoping there was some way to do it w/o globally interpreting `.html` as Twig. I guess there's no downside, other than it just feels wrong.

Comment: The only problem with this is that it re-assigns it from HTML files. So when you use html files again in another project you will have to switch it back. FYI.

Comment: You can solve this by adding *?html as a filetype. That way, everything that ends with .html will also get syntax highlighting without breaking regular html support.

Answer (score 4):

Even easier way… Just add `.html.twig` to `defaultTemplateExtensions` and update your template file extension to `.html.twig`. PHPStorm will pick up both html and twig syntax highlighting.

```
<?php

/**
 * General Configuration
 *
 * All of your system's general configuration settings go in here.
 * You can see a list of the default settings in craft/app/etc/config/defaults/general.php
 */

return array(
    'defaultTemplateExtensions' => array('html.twig', 'html'),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding `*.html` as a registered Twig patter, I use `*?html`.  Seems to work just fine and I don't have to switch back and forth.

On the flip side, Twig support in PhpStorm seems to contain all the HTML support as well, so other than feeling wrong (which it does), there may be no downside to just switching it over to Twig.